# wp_list_categories simulate offset

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

from what I can see, there is no parameter for offsetting in wp_list_categories (WordPress).

All I want to do is list child categories of a parent category; and begin always with the third child.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

This should help get you started. Just set $parent_cat_ID to whichever Category ID you're looking to target:

```
<ul id="category_list">
<?php
$categories = get_categories(array('child_of'=>$parent_cat_ID, 'hide_empty'=>0));
for($i=2;$i<count($categories);$i++)
    echo '<li class="category_item">'.$categories[$i]->cat_name.'</li>';
?>
</ul>
```